# File Buffer Size Too Small

Tags: c, file

I am trying to make a small program in C which reads in a file and calculates a CRC on the contents. I created the program in netbeans and in the IDE everything works. When I build the project with GCC and run the generated exe the program fails when reading in the file. The file is 1.3 Mb.

When reading in the file I eventually get the error "Internal error: TP_NUM_W_BUFS too small: 50"

My read code is fairly simple, it does very little line processing.

```
while (fgets(line, HEX_LINE_LENGTH, fp))
{
        int len = strlen(line);
        line[len] = line[len-1];
        line[len-1] = '\r';
        memcpy(&hex_lines[num_lines], line, HEX_LINE_LENGTH);
        num_lines++;
        printf("%s\n", line);
        memset(line, 0, HEX_LINE_LENGTH);
}
```

I am seeing a new issue. When reading in my file via the netbeans IDE everything works fine. When I compile the program from a command line with

```
g++ main.c crc_calculator.c crc_calculator.h -o crc
```

I get a crc.exe file. Running this will read in my file but will report that twice as many lines have been read than actually exist.

Comment: Try running your code though valgrind.  You may be mismanaging memory, and if so it should tell you where.

Comment: That is a great idea, I am looking into Dr Memory a windows suitable replacement

Comment: I have not run Dr Memory yet but I have a different result now. I am no longer getting the TP_NUM_W_BUFS error. However when reading in the file I see it read in half of the file then halt. I feel this is more of a buffer size issue rather than a memory leak, will investigate further.

Comment: Does the file contain any binary data?  Specifically, null bytes `'\0'` would cause problems with `fgets()`.  You'd also get CRLF to LF mapping during input unless you opened the input file with `"rb"` (where the `b` is important on Windows).  That would throw things off.  You appear to be trying to reinstate the CR (presumably because you didn't use binary mode), but you're assuming that `HEX_LINE_LENGTH` is sufficiently bigger than any line in your file.  You'd probably do better with `fread()` which won't map any characters for you.

Comment: Ok so using "rb" in netbeans gives me the same incorrect data as using "r" in the command line. I do believe this is CR LF encoding which is screwing with everything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you were also correct about the buffer size. I did not account for the \r\n characters and that was causing some weird issues.